# NavLink activeClassName not changing background color when clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

I am trying to make active class in React.js when ever I click on any NavLink I want background color to change

```
 <NavLink activeClassName="active3"
            
            exact={true}
            to="/client"
          >
            <div>
              <a href="#" className="nav_logo">
                <img className="slogo" src={forur} />
                <i className="fas fa-angry"></i>{" "}
              </a>
            </div>
          </NavLink>

 <NavLink activeClassName="active3" exact={true} to="/orders">
            <div>
              {" "}
              <a href="#" className="nav_logo">
                <Orders />
                <i className="fas fa-angry"></i>{" "}
              </a>
            </div>
          </NavLink>
```

App.css:

```css
.active3 div{
  background: black;
}
```